# Parâmetro Rotation no Jasper ou iReport não funciona ao exportar para formato ODS

Tags: java, microsoft-excel, ireport, jasper

Olá!

Meu código:

```
<staticText>
<reportElement mode="Opaque" x="282" y="0" width="59" height="82" backcolor="#C4C4C4" uuid="8c5029ee-1b1d-41e8-a82f-ef2f879009c0"/>
<box>
    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
</box>
<textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" rotation="Left">
    <font fontName="Arial" size="11" isBold="true"/>
    <paragraph lineSpacing="Single"/>
</textElement>
<text><![CDATA[Matrícula]]></text>
```

O parâmetro está aí (rotation="Left"), mas não funciona quando exportado para o formato ODS. Funciona quando utilo PDF ou XLS. (Utilizo o LibreOffice para visualização)

Já estou há vários dias pesquisando na internet, na documentação e na comunidade do Jasper, mas não encontrei nenhum caso onde o formato exportado é ODS.